# Cronjob cron.daily does not run (debian)

Tags: cron, debian

I got a script to run daily at any time. So `/etc/cron.daily` seems to be an easy solution.

But now I got the problem, the cronjob won't run that script. It seems like the cronjob won't run any of the daily jobs.

So I tried to put it to cron.hourly and everything worked fine.
But I dont want to run the backup script every hour.

`/etc/init.d/cron start|stop` works without errors.

`/etc/crontab` looks like default:

```
 m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report     /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

As it won't run I tried to install anacron but without any changes.

Why does it run the hourly scripts but not the daily ones?

Many thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 6):

It might be, that one of your daily-scripts is misbehaving. Try running them manually. I removed the logwatch package and the cron.daily job and it worked again.

This is my /etc/crontab

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
16 * * * * root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
12 2 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
41 1 * * 7 root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
9 3 30 * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

try running the daily like so

```
 run-parts -v --report /etc/cron.daily
```

you can also use --list or --test for more output. In my case I removed the misbehaving script and the daily job worked again

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with one of my scripts in /etc/cron.daily
The name of the script was backupBugzilla.sh

After renaming the script to backupBugzilla it worked.

Answer (score 4):

the manpage of run-parts states:

If  neither  the  `--lsbsysinit`  option nor the `--regex` option is given then the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters, ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.

I assume it does not like the name of your script. for example it does not like the extension ".sh" as a dot is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have anacron installed?

```
# dpkg --get-selections | grep anacron
```

If yes, it doesn't runs the daily, weekly and monthly scripts.

Comment: Well, I tried both ways. First without anacron, later I installed it.
But nothing changed.

Comment: _"If yes, it doesn't runs the daily, weekly and monthly scripts."_ - That is simply untrue as far as I know; can you provide a source?

Comment: Works for me with no anacron installed

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, and it was because the owner of my script in `/etc/cron.daily` was not root. Make root the owner of all the scripts in `/etc/cron.daily`:

```
sudo chown root /etc/cron.daily/*
```

Also, be sure the scripts are executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/*
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a wheezy not start the `/etc/init.d/anacron`.

My solution:

`edit /etc/init.d/anacron`

Required-Start: $all

save and run:

`update-rc.d /etc/init.d/anacron defaults`

now works well when wheezy start.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had two issues that caused the very same problem:

1. The script had a dot in the filename (`script.sh`) and run-parts wouldn't run that script. Renaming it to just `script` got me a step further.
2. run-parts complained about an incorrect executable format (or similar). Adding the shebang (like `#!/bin/bash`) at the beginning of the file solved that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Debian, unlike the EL distros, only runs files in these dirs that **do not have an extension**.

So anything with a .sh or .pl extension will not be run.

You can test and verify this but running  `run-parts --test -v --report /etc/cron.daily` first, then renaming one of your .pl or .sh scripts, then re-running

(Thanks to other commenters who helped me trace this)